# Visual Studio 11 metro apps unable to add reference?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Windows 8 and Visual Studio 11 to develop metro style apps. But each time i try to create Metro app project the projects get created but in reference there is nothing added  but the project builds successfully and even its not allowing me to add any reference dll.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wait a couple more days for the Beta (end of the month). It will be more stable.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Using the separate download for VS11 doesn't work, the installer is just plain broken.  Only the download that combines Win8 and VS11 works.  Three more days until the beta, just wait for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What are you adding a reference to? Metro style apps can only add references to other Metro style class libraries or portable class libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Metro style applications targets .NETCore framework if dependent solution is built on .NetFramework it can't be used in Metro style apps. For now you cannot rebuild your .NETFramework libraries on .NETCore because it has limited access(only for Windows Store apps).